# What's a the word for people who make fun of themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, epithet-requests, humor

I don't mean people with low self esteem.

But there are people who feel happy at being able to make other people laugh at their own expense. I remember someone telling me there is a word for them, I can't find it.

Let me explain:

I sometimes, while sitting with a group of people, might just tell them a personal embarrassing story, which might be completely fabricated, to make other people laugh. And when they laugh, I feel happiness.

I'm also self deprecating, but not in a way that I hate myself, rather,  just my work (I'm a screenwriter) and knowing I can do better. I do not self deprecate myself in public (I don't praise myself either).

Edit: Now that its mentioned, I think the word I'm talking about was used to describe a person's sense of humor. Or it could be a word used to describe a psychological trait/disorder.

Edit: I just looked up humor styles on Wikipedia. And after reading it, I guess the word that closely matches what I'm looking for is 'Affiliated Humor' but in a 'Self Defeating' style.

Comment: *self-deprecating*

Comment: @deadrat well.. self deprecating would be a likely personality trait. But I don't think it completely fits. I'll post some more detail to explain.

Comment: I think @deadrat is right on here with *self-deprecating*.  This feels like [this sketch from Kids in the Hall](http://youtu.be/QGYJyeX-oMc)

Comment: self-effacing? ~

Comment: @V0ight that's closer than self deprecating... But self effacing would be a person who doesn't attract much attention to himself.

Comment: Please write an example sentence where you would use the word or phrase. The following is the strict guideline of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).  Please edit your question.

Comment: also sense of self-mockery or self-derision.

Comment: notANerdDev: @deadrat's suggestion, self-deprecating, is exactly the word that fits your description. It is almost always collocated in 'a self-deprecating sense of humor'. None of the other suggestions have this connotation. 'affiliated' and 'self-defeating' have none of the connection with humor. Note the great number of upvotes on the very first comment.

Comment: @notANerdDev - Do a Youtube search for Rodney Dangerfield. he is the quintessential self-deprecating comedian.

Comment: Please write an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used. Are you looking for a noun, adjective? Please visit the tag information and see how a "Single Word Request" question works. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

The term you are looking for is ***[self-deprecating](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self-deprecating)***. [The Oxford Dictionary of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1614&dq=Modest%20about%20or%20critical%20of%20oneself,%20especially%20humorously%20so:%20%E2%80%98self-deprecating%20jokes%E2%80%99&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrqMKruv_PAhVK4GMKHSIdBk8Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Angus Stevenson defines the word as meaning:

> Modest about or critical of oneself, especially humorously so: ‘*self-deprecating jokes*’

Comment: I agree that what you meant to put is the right answer, you should correct the spelling and quote a definition with a link so that we can see *why* this is what OP is looking for. Once you do that you’ve got my upvote.

Comment: The OP already included **self-deprecating** in the question. "I'm also **self deprecating**, but not in a way that I hate myself,.."

Answer (score 5):

I think that what you are talking about is a personality trait known as

> being able to laugh at yourself

and

> not taking yourself too seriously

This quote of course can also describe someone's sense of humor and can mean a lot of things. For one, it could mean that you are so optimistic about your friends enjoying an embarrassing story about you that you are willing to admit any flaws or even make up a story to make them laugh. On the other hand it could mean that you are mentally strong. That you are able to accept your faults and be yourself. So the only word I could think of that could describe a person like this would be:

> [Humble](https://books.google.com/books?id=4XycAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA694&dq=having%20or%20showing%20a%20modest%20or%20low%20estimate%20of%20one's%20own%20importance&pg=PA694#v=onepage&q&f=false)): having or showing a modest or low estimate of one's own importance <sup>1</sup>

In your case, it would be a *modest* rather than a low estimate of one's own importance. I chose the word *humble* because you're willing to downplay yourself for the enjoyment of others, meaning that you do not care about looking "perfect" in front of others. You can be honest about your mistakes at times and still be okay with them. These are characteristics of *humility*.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Concise Oxford English Dictionary by Angus Stevenson and Maurice Waite

Comment: I think the word might be a psychology term. Someone with the background might know of it. I just know for sure that there is a word used to describe this behavior in specific. Anyways, your answer does make me feel good about myself and is not wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for:

> self-mockery (or self-mocking according to the [Oxford dictionnary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/definition/anglais/self-mocking))

Comment: Nope... Self mockery of simply an action. What I am referring to is not just an action. But also the realisation of the after effects of that action.